# Gatling gatling-sbt is missing

Tags: gatling

I cannot find

```
io.gatling:gatling-sbt
```

SBT plugin (2.2.1 or 2.2.0) 
in any repository.

Is it deprecated or something?

Sounds strange because official documentation still mentions it:

http://gatling.io/docs/current/extensions/sbt_plugin/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that io.gatling:gatling-sbt is not in the maven repository but Bintray:

https://bintray.com/gatling/sbt-plugins/gatling-sbt